# Why do I sometimes but not always end up with two heads on a branch in Mecurial?

Tags: mercurial

I sometimes but not always end up with two heads on my default branch. The sequence of events is something like:

```
hg pull
hg update -C default
hg branch mybranch
hg merge default //merge in default
hg commit -m"merged mybranch into default"
hg heads -default //shows 2 heads 
hg push --branch default //won't let ne. create 2 heads
```

The 'rival' head appears to be a changeset committed to default earlier in the day.

What I don't understand is why this happens sometimes and not other times.

The explanation I am usually offered is that the other guy pushed a change after I did a pull (my first action in the list above). But I think this happens in other cases e.g. when he pushed his changeset before I started.

I would have thought that when I pull default with his commit I get default with one head. My  merge/commit should just create a new head after that. Why does it create a second head?

Comment: An "hg log" showing the 2 heads would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a totally normal situation.  It's not a problem, or an error, or something to be avoided -- it's how a DVCS works.

In brief: you get two heads whenever two people start working from the same commit and do different things.  It doesn't matter if they do it in their own (named) branch (as you're doing above) or on `default`.  Once you merge your work back to `default` and someone else has done work on `default` you've got two heads and someone has to merge.  It's just how things are.

Before you push do a `hg pull` and then a `hg merge` and you'll integrate your work with yours,  by creating a new merge commit, with two parents -- your work and their work -- and then you push and you'll not see that warning.

Incidentally, you might want to check out the `bookmarks` feature.  It's better suited for per-feature branches like you appear to be doing above than the named branches you're using, but it in no way saves you from having to deal with multiple heads.

Answer (score 0):

1. check state of repository immediately after pull (pull can bring new head in default for you) with `hg heads`
2. `hg branch` without commit do nothing (you haven't mybranch)
3. Even if you'll create mybranch and merge it with default's tip (according to your syntax), it will not eliminate 2-nd head in default